# How to update 2 tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to update two tables called: routing and routing_has_work_center

In routing table, user can edit the description while in routing_has_work_center table, user can edit the production_hour.

```
<?php
session_start();
// include a php file that contains the common database connection codes
include ("dbFunctions.php");

//retrieve computer details from the textarea on the previous page
$description = $_POST['description'];
$production_hour=$_POST['$production_hour'];

//retrieve id from the hidden form field of the previous page
$theID = $_POST['routing_id'];

$msg = "";

//build a query to update the table
//update the record with the details from the form
$queryUpdate = "UPDATE routing SET description='$description' WHERE     routing_id = $theID";


//execute the query
$resultUpdate = mysqli_query($link, $queryUpdate) or die(mysqli_error($link));

//if statement to check whether the update is successful
//store the success or error message into variable $msg
if ($resultUpdate) {
$msg = "Record updated successfully!";
} else {
$msg = "Record not updated!";
}
?>
```

I have this the code above but when I update the production hour, it remains the same and is not updated at routing_has_work_center database.

Do I have to add something else to the query?

Comment: Have you heard of SQL Injection?

Comment: You need to have [talk with Bobby Tables' parents](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: There is only one line in the posted code with `production_hour` - i.e. `$production_hour=$_POST['$production_hour'];` - So what would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
$queryUpdate = "UPDATE routing_has_work_center SET production_hour='$production_hour' WHERE routing_id = '$theID' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update 2 tables, you need two UPDATE statements.
You have one.  You are missing the one for the `routing_has_work_center`.

Try something like this:

```
$update_routing_center = 'UPDATE routing_has_work_center SET production_hour = $production_hour WHERE routing_id = $theID"`
```

After putting this statement through `mysqli_prepare($link, $update_routing_center);`
you can then run the statement into the database.

Edit: Modified it to accomidate Ed Heal's comment

Comment: Please do not run this query like the other one - See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php to avoid SQL injection

Comment: As this anwer advises a fundamentally broken solution prone to SQL injection: -1

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I'm still new to programming, so I'm still learning some security concepts. @NielsKeurentjes

Comment: Just running the statement through `mysqli_prepare` doesn't suddenly make it safe it you still use concatenation in the 'master' string...